# Set Product Price programatically with weight and tax percentage in Magento

Tags: magento, product

I have a online jewellery store build with magento. The products are gonna be in gold. Since the gold price needs to be changed daily. we have planned to have a separate section to feed the gold price daily. now i wanna set the price of the any product with the global gold price obtained in the previous section with the weight of the product. There are also some more parameters involved in the price calculation like wastage, making charge, etc., I have planned to have those parameters has custom attributes to this attribute set.

Can any one please suggest be a idea to set the product price calculated with the weight and global gold price

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events of the `_afterLoad` event of the product model. You basically overwrite the standard product Model with a custom module and create an own product model class like:

```
<?php
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product
{
   protected function _afterLoad()
   {
       parent::_afterLoad();

       //you have access to the products data via $this->getData()
       $your_calculated_price = $this->getData('price') * 1.618; //or whatever your formula is
       $this->setData('my_calc_price', $my_calculated_price);
   }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is done each time you load a product, so this can be pretty resource intensive, depending on your calculations.

lg,

flo